# Aronszajn Trees and König's Lemma

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I'm looking at König's Lemma and Aronszajn Trees. I've seen the following link: [König's Infinity Lemma and Aronszajn Trees](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464694/k%C3%B6nigs-infinity-lemma-and-aronszajn-trees)

Long story short, I'm still left with two questions and I was wondering if anyone would either be able to point me in the right direction or explain why. I apologise if they're silly questions, I'm just very curious and can't quite deduce/find the answer myself.

1) Why does a proof in the style of König's Lemma break down for $\omega_{1}$? What is wrong with "Pick a node that has an uncountable number of successors as, if one doesn't exist, then you have a countable union of countable things which must (choice) be countable."? (Just to save time, why doesn't whatever goes wrong here also go wrong in the finite case? I've read it's about cardinal exponentiation, but don't quite understand.)

2) Does the fact that CH implies there exists an $\aleph_{2}$ Aronszajn Tree simply follow from theorem 7.10 in Kanamori's book (about $\kappa$ being regular and $2^{<\kappa}$ = $\kappa$) or is there an explicit construction I might be able to find somewhere? (or is the explicit construction simply the proof with $\aleph_2$ instead of $\kappa$?) My problem here is about CH. As far as I'm aware, $\aleph_{1}$ is regular using choice, so does CH give us the condition that $2^{<\aleph_{1}}$ = $\aleph_{1}$ and hence there is an $\aleph_{2}$ Aronszajn Tree?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the $\omega_1$ case, the reason is that at limit stages if we collect all the branches, we'll have uncountably many points, so we have to allow only a few branches to go through limit steps.

As for the second question, $\sf CH$ gives us exactly that $\aleph_1^{<\aleph_1}=\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, which is why there is an $\aleph_2$-Aronszajn tree. As for an explicit construction, you can start with these assumptions, and work through Specker's proof to have an explicit one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You seem to answer all of my questions. If I may: at limit steps you're limited to countably many points to take through? Therefore, there's no way to guarantee the point you're after goes through and so it breaks down?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't fully understand what you mean by that second part of the comment.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it seems to say that there can exist such a point, but there's no way to identify it. Why can you only allow a few branches through at the limit steps and why does the argument therefore fail? (What if you threw away the wrong point?) Does that make sense? I'm likely missing something obvious, such as a definition.

Comment: First let's clear the easy part. If you have above each point at least two successors, then after countably many points you embed the full binary tree. By allowing all the branches to be realized into a point on the limit step, you will necessarily have a level which is uncountable, and the tree is not an $\omega_1$-tree anymore. So in order to ensure that the tree has countable levels we have to limit which branches are realized. So just choosing by induction "the next point" which has uncountably many nodes above it doesn't necessarily goes through the limit step, [...]

Comment: OH!!!!! Yes, thank you. :D

Comment: [...] since you might be going on a branch which doesn't continue above that particular limit point. Therefore the usual argument from Koenig's lemma cannot work here.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I now understand! Thank you for taking the time to explain. :D

Comment: No problem, it's my pleasure.