# Normal tree with $\aleph_1$ nodes and no branch of cardinality $\aleph_1$

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I am trying to understand how a normal tree with $\aleph_1$ node can fail to have a branch of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Consider the tree of height $\omega_1$ whose nodes are $\mathbb{Q}$-valued strictly increasing $\alpha$-sequences.

This tree is normal : it has a single root; every node has a least to immediate successors; for every $\alpha < \beta < \omega_1$, if $x$ is on the $\alpha$-th level then there exist $y$ on the $\beta$-th level such that $x < y$.

This tree cannot have a branch of length $\omega_1$, for there would be an injection of $\omega_1$ into $\mathbb{Q}$.

> Why does a proof in the style of König's Lemma break down for ω1? What is wrong with "Pick a node that has an uncountable number of successors as, if one doesn't exist, then you have a countable union of countable things which must (choice) be countable."?

This question is closely related to [Aronszajn Trees and König's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978514/aronszajn-trees-and-k%C3%B6nigs-lemma)
but but I am not requiering that the tree be an Aronszajn tree.

Comment: It is not enough to have an uncountable number of successors. You need many of these successors to be comparable to each other in order to have a branch. In fact, at any level of the tree there is at least one node with the property you describe. This is not where the issue lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you going to carry the recursive construction of a branch beyond the first $\omega$ steps? Every node has uncountably many successors at the next higher limit level, so you can easily construct a strictly increasing sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of nodes, but if $\sup_n\sup x_n=\infty$, which is certainly possible, you won’t be able to extend this sequence of nodes any higher in the tree.

Comment: So if I understand it right, there is no branch of length $\omega_1$ because $\omega_1$ has enough limit level to ensure that any branch will eventually be unable to extend any higher. Am I right ?

Comment: @M.G: Yes — basically because you can’t embed $\omega_1$ in $\Bbb Q$.