# Comparing between $\omega_2$ and $\omega_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

My question, it seems very basic about cardinal numbers. I know $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable regular cardinal. Also, $\omega_2$ is the second uncountable regular cardinal.

I did not know how I can envision the difference between them. In other words, what are things that that might be achieved for $\omega_1$ but not for $\omega_2$ and so on.

Comment: I think this might be too broad to answer. There are **many** differences between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ - for example, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ [proves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronszajn_tree) that there is a tree of height $\omega_1$ with all levels countable and no branches of length $\omega_1$, but if weakly compact cardinals are consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then the tree property at $\omega_2$ is consistent (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4282/28111)). And there are more complicated results about ideals around them. What *sort* of distinguishing features are you looking for?

Comment: First uncountable regular cardinal is usually denoted with $\aleph_1$. Do you by any chance have *ordinals* in mind (rather than *cardinals*)?

Comment: @AdamZalcman Strictly speaking $\aleph_\alpha$ is the same thing as $\omega_\alpha$ (cardinals are exactly *initial ordinals*) - the notational difference is merely a context indicator (such indicators can be necessary since we use the same notation for cardinal and ordinal arithmetic operations, which of course are quite different - I personally despise this, but c'est la vie). And, arguably annoyingly, in set theory we often do talk abut $\omega_\alpha$ even when we're thinking of it as a cardinal. The OP's notation is fine.

Comment: For me, the more pronounced distinguishing features lie in consistency results without choice. For example, it is consistent to have $\omega_1$ be a countable union of countable sets in ZF, whereas ZF proves $\omega_2$ is not a countable union of countable sets. It is also consistent (relative to large cardinals) that the club filter on $\omega_1$ is an ultrafilter, whereas provably in ZF there are disjoint stationary subsets of $\omega_2$.

Comment: Re: @JasonZeshengChen's first observation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044535/omega-2-is-a-not-countable-union-of-countable-sets-without-ac) for the proof about $\omega_2$ (which is a very cute argument!).

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen: Your last statement is misleading. What happens if $\omega_1$ is singular?

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen I think your last statement requires "$\omega_1$ is regular," no?

Comment: that is right. I commented too quickly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber,  What I know about cardinals are very basic. I can see the different between $\omega$ and $\omega_1.$ But $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ I could not see it since both are uncountable and regular. How I can see how much  differ from each other

Comment: @00GB What does "how much differ from each other" mean? What sorts of questions are you interested in?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I do not have any specific problem in my mind. Okay, lets try this. You mentioned  in your first comments " they are many difference between"? right? Could you please point out the most important differences between them?

Comment: @00GB There **are no** "most important" differences. The comments above, including mine, have mentioned several; they are all reasonably important, and their relative importance is highly context-dependent. I really don't understand what sort of thing you're looking for. Maybe it would help if you can explain what you consider a satisfying difference between $\omega$ and $\omega_1$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, $\omega$ can be written as a countable union of countable sets but $\omega_1$ not. Also, Aronszajn tree and Koing theorem . I can see something true for $\omega$ but not for $\omega_1$ and the other way

Comment: @00GB OK, how about "$\omega_1$ can be written as a size-$\omega_1$ union of size-$\omega_1$ sets but $\omega_2$ cannot"? That's exactly analogous to your first example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120613/discussion-between-00gb-and-noah-schweber).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose I'll give this a stab after all. For me personally, there are two differences between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ which leap reflexively to mind whenever I consider them in the same thought.

- At an elementary level, there is a difference in the structure of **"natural" stationary sets** on each cardinal. In line with Jason Zesheng Chen's comment above, $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ proves that the club filter on $\omega_1$ is an ultrafilter. By contrast, consider $$A=\{\alpha\in\omega_2: cf(\alpha)=\omega\}\mbox{ and }B=\{\alpha\in\omega_2: cf(\alpha)=\omega_1\}.$$ As long as $\omega_1$ is regular (e.g. assuming countable choice) $A$ and $B$ are stationary but clearly $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
- On a more sophisticated level, the related structures $H_{\omega_1}$ and $H_{\omega_2}$ are quite different, model-theoretically speaking. Elements of $H_{\omega_1}$ are "morally equivalent" to real numbers, and so the first-order theory of $H_{\omega_1}$ is [relatively immune](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71965/a-limit-to-shoenfield-absoluteness) to set-theoretic shenanigans, especially granting large cardinals. We have no such tameness in $H_{\omega_2}$, however; for example, the continuum hypothesis can be turned on or off as desired by forcing and is equivalent to a first-order sentence in $H_{\omega_2}$. Indeed, the search for a theory to "tame" $H_{\omega_2}$ analogous to projective determinacy's impact on $H_{\omega_1}$ is a very difficult one. While much more complicated than the previous bulletpoint, this is actually *more* reflexive to me since I use the relative tameness of $H_{\omega_1}$ (or its moral equivalents) quite frequently in my own work.

But these are more technical differences: *why* should one care about natural stationary sets or model-theoretic tameness? Ultimately we're left with the bare fact that these ordinals are rather technical ($\omega_2$ especially), and ultimately a good picture of them will only emerge *after* (or at best, *during*) the process of learning how to work with them.

Comment: Noah Schweber, Thank you so much

Comment: I'm not sure your example in the first point is correct - if $\omega_2$ is singular with cofinality $\omega_1$ then you can find a cofinal subset of $\omega_2$ of length $\omega_1$ consisting of successor cardinals only. Its closure should then only contain limit ordinals of cofinality $\omega$, showing $B$ is not a club. Is it somehow impossible that $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_2)=\omega_1$? Relatedly, in the comments it is implied that the club filter on $\omega_2$ can be an ultrafilter if $\omega_1$ is singular, would you happen to have a reference?